# Paypal - What is "Executing Payment"?

Tags: paypal

Can someone tell me the difference between "creating payment" with "executing payment"? thanks.

Creating payment example: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/ExecutePayment.html

"executing payment" example: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/ExecutePayment.html

Comment: How do i get the payer_id for https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to create a payment.
You will pass all the variables required to Paypal and you will get back a redirect URL.
Only when you have the redirect URL you can send the user to approve the payment.
After the approval the user will be brought back to your website and in the response there will be a payerID.
Using the payer-ID you will execute the payment.

There is a description of the flow here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

Comment: Ok, how do i actually get the payer_id for 
 https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment

Comment: It is in the response when you are brought back by paypal. PayerID is appended to the URL.

Comment: i am using the mobile SDK.

Comment: 1. How do i get payer_id for https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment

2. My "scope" is always lacking when i tried to get payment data, for example, when i GET request to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3FV51785N7219224JK3BPI7Q (with access token header and return type header), i always get the response: 


   



I have checked all the ticks in App's settings. Thank you. Please email me back with the solution, your documentation is lacking on these 2 vitally important stuff.

Comment: {
      "name": "REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING",
      "message": "Access token does not have required scope",
      "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING",
      "debug_id": "67bd035169e93"
    }

Comment: oh ok sorry.. I never used the mobile SDK to be honest, I'll have a look maybe

Comment: it's these effing paypal documentation that is sucks.

Comment: I think that trying the android sdk might help you.

Comment: I found this? could be useful to you? https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/